# Replace CKEditor by class after .load()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ckeditor, rich-text-editor

I am using CKEditor for my website's blog posts but have an issue where after loading all the bog posts via `.load()` they no longer get replaced by CKEditors.

This is done example:

```
$("#container #postholder").load("http://url.com/viewblog.php?id=155 #container #postholder");
```

First, I had issues with the scripts that were called upon by items that were loaded via the `.load()` method. I solved this by changing the button call to this:

```
$(document).on('click','.edity',function(){ });
```

The buttons now work, but the CKEditor isnt.

Lets say I have 5 different instances that are on the page, they all have the generic class of `ckeditor` so they all work.

However, after the `.load()` of the items, they are not changed to CKEditors and instead stay text areas.

To solve this I tried this when clicking the 'edit' button:

```
$(document).on('click','.edity',function(){
     CKEDITOR.replace('.ckeditor');
});
```

That does not work, I then tried using the name of the CKEditors so:

```
$(document).on('click','.edity',function(){
     CKEDITOR.replace('editorName');
});
```

This works, even after the `.load()`, but it only works for the first instance. All of the other CKEditors are not changed into the CKEditor.

I cant see how to get around this...

Any one understand?

Editors are created like so:

This is in a foreach loop for each blog post result. The ckEID variable is the posts ID + 1.

```
<div class="editor">
<textarea name="muffin" id="'.$ckEID.'" class="ckeditor">'.$text.'</textarea>
</div>
```

I use this:

```
$(document).on('click','.edity',function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.editor').toggle();
    CKEDITOR.replace('ckeditor');
});
```

To convert the text area when the edit button is clicked.

Just tried using replaceAll and the error console showed e.g.

```
uncaught exception: The editor instance "message" is already attached to the provided element.
```

I have other text areas on the page and it seems that everything is getting messed up when using replaceAll.

Comment: I know for a fact that ckeditor won't work unless the textarea has an `id` assigned to it.

Comment: my ckeditors are created dynamicly via a PHP foreach. I generate a unique ID for each of the text areas.

Comment: OK, I might be wrong but I think you need to use that ID inside the `replace` function. This might not be related to your main issue however.

Comment: i have tried it all. Only seems to work when using the text area name and then its only for the first instance. The replaceAll doesn't work neither. Thanks for trying though :)

Comment: Try `replace("theID")` not `replace("#theID")` nor `replace(".theID")`

Comment: it works let say for the ID. However it only works for the first one still because im guessing all the ckeditors need a unique ID. no luck by class, but is there a way to say replace all of the IDS that have a value of 1 - 50. If i was to do a +1 everytime for the textarea id then that might work?

Comment: Yes, you absolutely need **unique** IDs.

Comment: This is what I use to generate unique IDs `$selector.attr("id", "ckeditor-" + Date.now() + "-" + Math.random().toString().split(".")[1] );`.

Comment: just tried giving them a unique id, and then doing e.g. replace('515'); replace('514'); this does replace both of them, but the content in the FIRST ckeditor looks to be part of the divs code and also one of the ckeditor scripts?

Comment: Check your developer console for errors. Hard to tell but this could be down to malformed HTML or some other bug. Perhaps you can update your question with this extra information?

Comment: hmm, ill have a look. So annoying as any textarea with the ckeditor class should be converted. It just doesnt work after the .load() EDIT: Got the as the error: uncaught exception: The editor instance "515" is already attached to the provided element.

Comment: Please edit your question and show how (a) you're creating the textareas with their IDs and (b) how you're replacing them to convert them to CKeditors.

Comment: Just added some information.

Comment: You need to replace each ID instead of `CKEDITOR.replace('ckeditor');`

Comment: that was an example. If there are 2 text areas with IDs of 515 and 514, and i do CKEDITOR.replace('514'); CKEDITOR.replace('515'); thats when the first editor is filled with html and the ckeditor script

Comment: please show the rendered HTML in your question, rather than the PHP.

Comment: school boy error on my part. There was another div that used the same id as the text area. So there was more than 1 div / textarea with that id. Changed the naming of the divs and it worked fine! One last question, the div ids will range from between 1 and could go to 99999999 etc. Any way to say if the div id is between 1 and 9999999?

Comment: actually i could try e.g $(this).parent().find('.ckeditor').getTHEID(); replace('ckeditor id'); I know that wont work untill i know how to get the id, but its a better way i think

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean...

Comment: just use `.attr("id")`

Comment: Just created a another question for this part incase it might be useful to others. Final part of this problem for me. Thanks for the help!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21503255/get-the-id-of-a-textarea-from-this-html-form-with-jquery