# get the id of a textarea from this html form with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, attr

Need help getting and using the `id` of a textarea so that I can replace it with a ckEDITOR.

So here is the `html` output:

NOTE: This is the output of a `foreach` loop, for every database result, this is the `html` output and the textarea ID is a number generated from the `id` of the row.

```
<div class="blogtest" id="514">
<form action="process/updatepost.php" class="updatepost" method="post">
<input type="button" class=edity value="Edit">
// SOME BUTTONS
<br>
<div class="text">
<div class="buildtext" id="514">3</div>
<div class="editor">
<textarea name="muffin" id="516" class="ckeditor">3</textarea>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

And here is the jQuery im using:

```
$(document).on('click','.edity',function(){
var editorID = $(this).find('.ckeditor').attr("id")
CKEDITOR.replace(editorID);
});
```

This doesnt work, I'm not the most advanced with jQuery so not sure why. But i get a type b is undefined error in my console log.

Also just to note; this works:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('516');
```

but the text areas are loaded dynamically in a `foreach` loop and I can't be creating a replace code for 1000's of editors...

Comment: Do all your textareas use the same ID? IDs **must** be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `.checkeditor` element from the `.edity` element. Instead you can do:

```
$(document).on('click','.edity',function() {
    var editorID = $(this).parents('.blogtest').find('.ckeditor').attr("id");
    CKEDITOR.replace(editorID);
});
```

Comment: hero. New it was something simple. Now i know about the parent part for the future. I shall mark this is as correct when i can :) Thanks!

Comment: Can I find all siblings ids ?